How to get the Pipeline rawlog in a structured format using API call?
I am able to get the log data in the pipeline in unstructured format using API call.
I want to get the pipeline log data in structured format Using single GET API call
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs/{$logId}?api-version=7.1-preview"

This is the reference API I am getting the pipeline raw log in unstructured format.
I want to get the output in structured format with single API call(GET).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What structured format output do you mean? You need to provide examples of what you expect to see to clarify. Otherwise we can't guess what exactly it is.

Hi , i am getting the output of the pipeline log as a page but i need only the contents

I am getting like this2024-10-17T17:49:14.5470566Z
2024-10-17T17:49:14.5470878Z [33;1mVERBOSE: Command [Set-AzContext] succeeded.[0m
2024-10-17T17:53:01.4640999Z Users inactive for 20 days
2024-10-17T17:53:01.4725215Z [
2024-10-17T17:53:01.4725733Z   {
2024-10-17T17:53:01.4726735Z     "UserPrincipalName": "",
2024-10-17T17:53:01.4733075Z     "LastLogin": "2024-09-27T12:16:37.167847Z",
2024-10-17T17:53:01.4734039Z     "HostPoolName": "",
2024-10-17T17:53:01.4734310Z     "SessionHostName": "<>",
2024-10-17T17:53:01.4734715Z     "DaysInactive": 20.0
2024-10-17T17:53:01.4735012Z   },

Can you format the output sample and update the question?

From your sample shared in the comment, it seems that you need to extract the actual output from the script and ignore the default output log of the task.
I am afraid that there is no single Rest API can directly get the actual output log. Currently, it only supports outputting the entire task log.
To meet your requirement, I suggest you use PowerShell regular expressions to extract each element one by one.
Here is an example:
Pipeline Output:

PowerShell Script sample:
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/{BuildId}/logs/{logid}"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

$regex = 'Users(\s([A-Za-z0-9]+\s)+)days'
$Inactiveday= [regex]::matches($response, $regex).value
$regex = '"UserPrincipalName":"[A-Za-z]+"'
$UserPrincipalName= [regex]::matches($response, $regex).value
$regex = '"HostPoolName": "[A-Za-z]+"'
$HostPoolName= [regex]::matches($response, $regex).value
$regex = '"SessionHostName": "[A-Za-z]+"'
$SessionHostName= [regex]::matches($response, $regex).value
$regex = '"DaysInactive": [0-9]*\.[0-9]+'
$DaysInactive= [regex]::matches($response, $regex).value
$regex = '"LastLogin": "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]+)?([Zz]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?"'
$LastLogin= [regex]::matches($response, $regex).value


echo $Inactiveday
$Output= "
{
  $UserPrincipalName,
  $HostPoolName,
  $SessionHostName
  $DaysInactive,
  $LastLogin
}"
echo $Output

Result:

Note: You need to generate wildcards based on your actual output. You can use this site to convert the regular expressions : Regex Generator

yeah this i am able to achieve but with single API i want to get in this format

@Mmkv I am afraid that there is no  single rest api can directly achieve this feature. We need to use additional script to get this format

sorry with powershell scrip i achieved it

@Mmkv Glad to know that you can achieve it now. Do you have any further questions?
